# Determining the asymptotic distribution [updated]

Tags: probability, statistics

**EDIT:** I have made progress in my original question, so I have decided to rewrite the entire question to reflect what help I am now seeking.

Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n} \sim \mathrm{unif}[0,\theta]$ IID, with $\theta > 0$. I would like to determine the asymptotic distribution of $Y_{n} = n(X_{(n)} - \theta)$.

\begin{align*}
F(t) &= P(n(X_{(n)} - \theta) \leq t) \\
&=P \left(X_{(n)} \leq \frac{t}{n} + \theta \right) \\
&= P \left( U_{(n)} \leq \theta^{-1} \left( \frac{t}{n} + \theta \right) \right)\\
&= \left( \frac{\theta + (\frac{t}{n})}{\theta}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}

So the asymptotic distribution function is given by $F(t) = e^{t/\theta}$ for $t \in (-\mathbb{R}\theta, 0)$. Does everything look okay with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Pr[X_{(n)} \le x] = \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i \le x] = (x/\theta)^n, \quad 0 \le x \le \theta,$$  hence $f_{X_{(n)}}(x) = nx^{n-1}/\theta^n$. So $$f_{Y_n}(y) = f_{X_{(n)}}(y/n+\theta)\cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{(y/n+\theta)^{n-1}}{\theta^n} = \frac{1}{\theta} \left(1 + \frac{y/\theta}{n}\right)^{n-1}, \quad -n \theta \le y \le 0.$$  So the asymptotic distribution is $$f_{Y_\infty}(y) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{y/\theta}, \quad -\infty \le y \le 0,$$ which we recognize as the negative of an exponential distribution; i.e., $Y_\infty = -U$, where $U \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$, $\operatorname{E}[U] = \theta$.